# First time pivot SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, pivot

I needed help with pivoting a table. This is my first attempt.

I have extracted data into a #temp table. I have two columns, in my #temp table, `Customer Nr` and `product`

One customer number can have more than one 1 product. How do I show, for one customer number, up to 3 products?

This is my very first attempt:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    cust_no,
    products
FROM 
    #temp
PIVOT 
    (cust_no, 
     CASE WHEN [Product 1] IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE [Product 2] END AS [Product 2],
     CASE WHEN [Product 2] IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE [Product 3] END AS [Product 3])
```

I got stuck here. I am working in SQL Server 2012

Comment: I have a follow-up question as it made me try a new thing. If I had in a table ,cust_no,product and serviceid, The ServiceId corresponding to each product. How can I make sure the service ID is next to the respective product number? I basically copy pasted the row_number() line and modified it to include serviceid. The problem is that, it requires me to includes an aggregate function to allow the query to work. I tried doing MAX(serviceid) and it does end next to the productname, however it is for some other product. Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need to use the `PIVOT` function to get the result. You could use an aggregate function with a CASE expression, along with a windowing function like `row_number()` to convert the data from rows into columns.  The windowing function will generate a unique number for each product within a customer. This number is then used to place the value into each of the columns.

Here is some sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE temp
    ([CustomerNr] int, [Product] varchar(9));

INSERT INTO temp
    ([CustomerNr], [Product])
VALUES
    (1234, 'Rice'),
    (1234, 'Tuna'),
    (1234, 'Sauce'),
    (2345, 'Jam'),
    (3456, 'Spaghetti'),
    (3456, 'Jelly');
```

Using an aggregate function and a CASE expression your code would be:

```
select CustomerNr,
  Product1 = max(case when rn = 1 then Product else null end),
  Product2 = max(case when rn = 2 then Product else null end),
  Product3 = max(case when rn = 3 then Product else null end)
from
(
  select CustomerNr, Product,
    rn = row_number() over(partition by customerNr order by product)
  from temp
) d
group by CustomerNr;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e6f67/2).

But if you wanted to use the PIVOT function you can you'll just still need to use a windowing function to help determine the number of products for each Customer:

```
select CustomerNr, Product1, Product2, Product3
from
(
  select CustomerNr, Product,
    new_col = 'Product'
                +cast(row_number() over(partition by customerNr order by product) as varchar(1))
  from temp
) d
pivot
(
  max(product) 
  for new_col in (Product1, Product2, Product3)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e6f67/3). Either version will give a result:

```
| CustomerNr | Product1 |  Product2 | Product3 |
|------------|----------|-----------|----------|
|       1234 |     Rice |     Sauce |     Tuna |
|       2345 |      Jam |    (null) |   (null) |
|       3456 |    Jelly | Spaghetti |   (null) |
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you for helping and teaching the easier way of doing it:=) I completely forgot my old friend , ROW_NUMBER() OVER. Much appreciated.!